# two-way binding using v-model is not working. browser error/warning: withDirectives can only be used inside render functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Using VITE v5.0.8.

This is the dex.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Vue To Do App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app" class="col-md-6">
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/maindex.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the maindex.js File

```
import './assets/main.css'
import appdex from './components/appdex.vue';

const app = Vue.createApp(appdex)

app.mount('#app')
```

This is the appdex.vue file.

```
<template>
    <div id="app" class="col-md-6">
        <input v-model="value">
        {{ value }}
    </div>
      
</template>
  
<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            value: ''
        }
    },

}

</script>
```

I am expecting that as I type in the text box, the value variable will be updated simultaneously.

This is the warning in the broswer
[Vue warn]: withDirectives can only be used inside render functions.

This is my first time using Stack Overflow and also have just started to learn Javascript and Vue Js. Please forgive any mistakes in presenting my doubt or if it is not a good one.

I have found a similar error in [text](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/3446)

The solution provided is :

Add this to hello-app/vue.config.js, see #1503 for details

`config.resolve.alias.set('vue$', resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue'))`

But I am using VITE and node_modules/vue doesn't make sense cause its not there in my project directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that you are receiving a warning about using v-model in your Vue component. When you use v-model outside of the render function, you usually get the warning "withDirectives can only be used inside render functions".

You are attempting to use v-model directly on an input element in your appdex.vue file. On the other hand, the render function's custom component or element should employ the v-model directive.

You can make the following changes to your appdex.vue file to resolve this issue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" class="col-md-6">
        <input :value="value" @input="updateValue">
        {{ value }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            value: ''
        };
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue(event) {
            this.value = event.target.value;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. But then I can only use v-model in custom components or elements? Also how do i write this javascript code in script setup format?

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` basically stands for `@update:model-value`. Since you are using it on plain input tag it does nothing. `v-model` can be used when you have created component that has `modelValue` prop and also is using 'update:modelValue' emit. Then you can expect your 'modelValue' value to change. But like answered before, you can listen to `@input` event and update your value like that.